# How to create a series in a dataframe that returns a value if another series contains a specific string?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dictionary

I am trying to see whether I can create a series in a dataframe that returns a value for a cell depending on whether the cell in another series contains a given string. Let me explain:

I have a dataframe with columns "restaurant_name" and "brand_name"

```
data = [["mcdonalds central london", ""], ["pizza hut downtown new york" ,""], 
        ["dominos new jersey",""], ["mac donald berlin", ""]]

restaurants = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['restaurant_name', 'brand_name'])
```

I have a dictionary with strings as keys and formatted brand names as values. I want the algorithm to check if restaurants["restaurant_name"] contains a key from brand_dictionary and if it does I want it to return the value corresponding to that key in data["brand_name"]

```
brand_dictionary = {
"mcdonalds" : "McDonald's",
"mac donald" : "McDonald's",
"dominos" : "Dominos Pizza",
"pizza hut" : "Pizza Hut"}
```

Really not sure how to do this..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use custom function in `.apply()` to search the dictionary (If no brand is found `-` is returned):

```
import pandas as pd


data = [["mcdonalds central london", ""], ["pizza hut downtown new york" ,""], ["dominos new jersey",""], [ "mac donald berlin", ""] ]

restaurants = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['restaurant_name', 'brand_name'])
    
brand_dictionary = {
"mcdonalds" : "McDonald's",
"mac donald" : "McDonald's",
"dominos" : "Dominos Pizza",
"pizza hut" : "Pizza Hut"}

def get_name(restaurant, dct):
    for r in dct:
        if r in restaurant:
            return dct[r]
    return '-'

restaurants['brand_name'] = restaurants['restaurant_name'].apply(lambda x: get_name(x, brand_dictionary))
print(restaurants)
```

Prints:

```
               restaurant_name     brand_name
0     mcdonalds central london     McDonald's
1  pizza hut downtown new york      Pizza Hut
2           dominos new jersey  Dominos Pizza
3            mac donald berlin     McDonald's
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `str.extract` the first word that matches and then map the match with the dictionary.

```
pat = f'({"|".join(brand_dictionary.keys())})'
#'(mcdonalds|mac donald|dominos|pizza hut)'

df['brand_name'] = df['restaurant_name'].str.extract(pat)[0].map(brand_dictionary)

               restaurant_name     brand_name
0     mcdonalds central london     McDonald's
1  pizza hut downtown new york      Pizza Hut
2           dominos new jersey  Dominos Pizza
3            mac donald berlin     McDonald's
```

---

If you want to deal with the possibility of multiple matches on a single row you can switch to `str.extractall` and then use some aggregation, like a list, to store all of the Brands that match.

```
df['brand_name'] = (df['restaurant_name'].str.extractall(pat)[0].map(brand_dictionary)
                      .groupby(level=0).agg(list))

               restaurant_name       brand_name
0     mcdonalds central london     [McDonald's]
1  pizza hut downtown new york      [Pizza Hut]
2           dominos new jersey  [Dominos Pizza]
3            mac donald berlin     [McDonald's]
```

Comment: thank you! I have more trouble understanding it that @Andrej Keselys answer but this definitely works and also the aggregation part is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Hmm make sure all the elements in dictionary are strings like

```
 brand_dictionary = {
   "mcdonalds" : "McDonald's",
   "mac donald" : "McDonald's",
   "dominos" : "Dominos Pizza",
   "pizza hut" : "Pizza Hut"}
```

then, we could loop like:

```
brand_names = []
for i in range(0, restaurants.shape[0]):
    # read the name in the column 
    current_key =  restaurants['restaurant_name'].iloc[i]
    try:
        # Now if that name exists in dictionary, check its value and add that to list
        brand_names.append(brand_dictionary[current_key])
    except:
        #If that key dosent exist in dict, then just add nan, or 'NA'
        brand_names.append(np.nan) # or.append('NA')

#Add the final list to main dataframe.
restaurants['BrandNames'] = brand_names
```